# Как реализовать рандом без повтора чисел?

Tags: python

например есть 100 чисел от 1 до 100, каждое число нужно выдавать рандомно без повтора

Comment: Для коротких последовательностей можно сначала создать список нужных значений: `l = range(1, 101)` затем перемешать его: `random.shuffle(l)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import random
l = list(range(1, 101))
random.shuffle(l)
for i in l:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Букву `l` легко с `1` перепутать. Лучше `L` использовать.

Comment: Для чего если не секрет range оборачивается в list? Вроде range и так list возвращает.

Comment: В python 3 range возвращает генератор.

Comment: Точно, спасибо, про 3 ветку не подумал.

Answer (score 2):

Один из вариантов - использовать [линейный конгруэнтный генератор псевдослучайных чисел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4). Например, чтобы получить все числа от 0 до 99, используйте начальное приближение - любое x, например,`x=17` а затем вызывайте сто раз процедуру `x = (21*x+1) mod 100`. Ясно, что для получения всех чисел от 1 до 100 нужно прибавить  единичку к полученной последовательности, то есть на каждом шаге делать `y[i]=x+1`, чтобы получить массив y[] с желаемым для вас свойством. Более точно подбор коэффициентов линейного генератора рассмотрен по ссылке.

Второй способ - создать массив чисел от 1 до 100 и случайно его перемешать.